# How to pass uploaded file into amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, flask

I have this in my code:

```
size=128,128
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
        print request.method
        if request.method == 'POST':
                file = request.files['image']
                im = Image.open(file)
                im.resize(size)
                im.save("test.png","PNG")
                f=open("test.png",'r')
                conn = tinys3.Connection('AKIAI2GPQ','fAQxDLbvZcqhXvjd',tls=True)    
                conn.upload(im,f,"snappie.watermarks")
                print "got file"
                return redirect("https://www.google.com")
         return render_template('index.html')
```

hopefully you can see that I am trying to handle the file upload from request.files, resize it, and then upload that to amazon s3. However right now its getting hung up on the `conn.upload(im,f,"snappie.watermarks")` line.

This is the error:

```
File "/home/alex/snappie/web/server.py", line 25, in upload
conn.upload(im,f,"snappie.watermarks")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tinys3/connection.py", line 152, in upload
return self.run(r)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tinys3/connection.py", line 233, in run
return self._handle_request(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tinys3/connection.py", line 255, in _handle_request
return request.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tinys3/request_factory.py", line 147, in run
headers['Content-Type'] = self.content_type or mimetypes.guess_type(self.key)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 298, in guess_type
return _db.guess_type(url, strict)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 114, in guess_type
scheme, url = urllib.splittype(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1074, in splittype
match = _typeprog.match(url)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Apparently its having issues with one of those 3 arguments but I am not sure which one? I am also not sure I am handling the file correctly. Do I need to save the image and then re-open it in order to upload it to amazon s3? I do this because all the tinys3 examples do so, but my file is already open so perhaps its redundant?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your image argument might be mixed up. Here's the signature we want:

```
conn.upload(key, local_file, bucket)
```

tinys3 [expects a string value for the key](https://github.com/smore-inc/tinys3/blob/master/tinys3/connection.py#L102) and an open file-like object for local_file. Try the following:

```
conn.upload("test.png", f, "snappie.watermarks")
```